# MikTeX: How to run pdflatex from cmd prompt on Windows 7 compared to Windows XP?

Tags: pdftex, miktex, windows

In Windows XP I create my `test.tex` in emacs and then run it in the cmd promt as `pdflatex test.tex` in the corresponding directory, and it works without a problem. However, in Windows 7 doing the same thing I need to use the full file path in the cmd promt `pdflatex "...dir/test.tex"` and then it runs but stops because it can't find the `test.aux` file, probably since the program looks for it in the current directory where the `test.tex` file is located.

How can one do this in Windows 7?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Then you are in the wrong directory, when `pdflatex` is called. What is your working directory and where is the `.tex` file?

Comment: My .tex file is in my "working directory" together with the auxillary files and picture files. pdflatex is located in the bin directory under the MikTeX installation directory and it is added to PATH. When running the command in the cmd promt I am in my "working directory", so I was thinking the program should look in the same directory for the auxillary files as the .tex as it does on WinXP, but apparently not on Win7?

Comment: I have no problem in using TeXLive or MikTeX in Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit.

Answer (score 9):

AFAIK MiKTeX does not like, if the working directory is inside its `texmf` tree.
Use a working directory outside.

Comment: That did it! Thank you both very much for your fast and concise help. Per aspera ad astra... :)

Comment: @Adam If response from `@Heiko Oberdiek` solved your issue you may want to mark his/her response as an `Answer` so other readers can benefit better from the response. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have your `tex` file in the directory `mytexfiles`. If MiKTeX is proper installed you can just open the command line, change into your directory with `cd ...\mytexfiles` (change `...` with the correct path or do it step by step). Then you can invoke LaTeX with `pdflatex test.tex` to compile `test.tex` and receiving `test.aux` etc.

Easier is to install a good editor and run LaTeX from within the editor ...

Comment: Yes, exactly, that's how I do it on WinXP. But apparently it does not work on Win7, since I have to include the full file path when running 'pdflatex "full file path"' in the cmd prompt, otherwise pdflatex does not find the tex file.